# Two F1 visas with different expiration dates

Tags: f1-visas

I have an old F1 visa, which is valid for 5 years and a new F1 visa, which is only valid for one year. The old visa was not cancelled when I got the new visa. Since the new visa is much shorter than the old one, it expires before the old one.

Is it safe to travel with the old visa? Is it still valid after all?

Comment: That's odd.  Why did you apply for a new visa more than one year before the old one expired?  Are they in the same passport?

Comment: Did you use the old visa?

Comment: @phoog yes they are in the same passport. I got the wrong information that I need to apply for a new visa when I change school and SEVIS ID

Comment: @Traveller Yes the old visa was used once.

Comment: It's also odd that they didn't cancel the old visa.  I suppose that it was an oversight.